# Why doesn't position: absolute work for element .profession in my code?

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner Frontend developer and decided to typeset a layout I found on the web. I tried to give position: absolute to the  element, but it didn't work out. With margin: 0 0; it is not in the upper left corner of the page, but somewhere in the middle. It doesn't have parent elements, especially with position: relative, so I'm confused. The span 'UX | UI Designer 24 years old, Minsk' (in the end both in HTML and CSS) is supposed to fall out of the normal flow so I could place it on the page wherever I want, but for whatever reason it doesn't work. Could you help me figure out why?

https://codepen.io/cocoa-cup/pen/GRByrQy

Here's the link to the layout:
[Figma link](https://www.figma.com/file/EWsHrotgKp5IPRIgl6kB6p/Free--Landing--Page-Template-(Copy)?node-id=0%3A1&t=rgbArLnyjEvtE7zp-1)

```
    <body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul class="navigation-list">
                <li class='menu-item'>Home</li>
                <li class='menu-item'>About me</li>
                <li class='menu-item'>Skills</li>
                <li class='menu-item'>Portfolio</li>
                <li class='menu-item'>Contacts</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div class="decoration-line">
        </div>
        <h1 class="name">Denis <br> Novik</h1>
        <span class="profession"> UX | UI Designer <br> 
            24 years old, Minsk </span>
    </header>
   
</body>
```

```
@font-face {
font-family:'Gilroy';
src: local('Gilroy'), url(./Gilroy-Bold.woff2);
font-weight:700;
font-style:bold;
```

}

```
@font-face {
font-family:'Gilroy-Medium';
src: local('Gilroy-Medium'), url(./Gilroy-Medium.woff2);
font-weight:400;
font-style:normal;}



 .navigation-list {
display: flex; 
justify-content:center;
margin-top:32.99px;
```

}

```
.menu-item {
list-style-type: none;
font-family: 'Gilroy';
font-style:bold;
margin-right:80px;
```

}

```
.decoration-line::after {
content:'';
display:block;
height:1px;
width:940.6px;
background-color: #828282;
margin: 40.5px auto 0 auto;
```

}

```
.name {
font-family:Gilroy;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:47.34px;
line-height:58.61px;
margin-left:251.04px;
```

}

```
.profession {
font-family:'Gilroy-Medium';
font-size:18px;
line-height:22px;

position:absolute;
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please have a read of the [help] and the [ask] section in particular - I would also recommend you take the [tour]. Please put a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) **into** your question... not an external liink

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, you want to position the text in the .profession span, in the upper left corner of the header. Is this right?

To do this, you will need to put position: relative on the <header> element, since it is the parent of .profession. Then, in .profession, you need to specify top: 0; left: 0; This will position in in the upper left corner. You may need to adjust things from there, but that will get you mostly there.